# How to resolve errors in grails application after upgrading to 2.3.6

Tags: grails, grails-2.3, grails-2.0.4

I recently updated my grails project from `2.0.4` to `2.3.6`, which is giving some errors while saving a form which contains multipart data (file attachments),

Its giving me the error for the file attachment fields like `rejected value: grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():`

And its giving me the error in `Requestmap.groovy` as well, below is the error

```
Requestmap.url.unique.error
```

In version 2.0.4, its working fine without any errors.

How to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2):

Grails documentation contains tips on updating from one version to another. In your case you are making a large jump so you may have to refer to the following:

[Upgrade from versions previous to 2.2](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html)

[Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html)

Both issues you have are validation errors. You can see the validation errors in detail by executing:

```
Requestmap requestmap = new Requestmap([...])
requestmap.validate()
println requestmap.errors
```

You can find additional details about validation errors in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html).